# MySQL select all rows from table with distinct ID using newest timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically,

```
id      status       timestamp

1       Good         0
2       Good         1
1       Bad          2
```

I want to have

```
id      status       timestamp

2       Good         1
1       Bad          2
```

returned to me.

This is because I want to know the most recent status of all the ids in the table. I've tried something naive like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_tbl group by id order by 'timestamp' desc;
```

But that obviously won't work, any idea? I'm sure it's very simple but I cannot figure it out :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ..
Join is much faster than sub query.

```
select t1.* From Table t1
LEFT JOIN Table t2 on t2.id=t1.id and t2.timestamp > t1.timestamp
where t2.id IS NULL.
```

Comment: Well done sir, for a table of 20 entries, your sql performs best :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.id, t1.status, t1.timestamp
from my_tbl as t1
where t1.timestamp = (select max(timestamp)
                      from my_table t2
                      where t1.id = t2.id)
```

This will however return ids twice which have the same highest timestamp.

Comment: You can use even joins.Sub query will take time if data are more.

Comment: @VatsalShah: is MySQL still bad with (co-related) sub-queries?

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use the `not exists` form for this:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_tbl t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM my_tbl t2
                  WHERE t2.id = t.id and t2.timestamp > t.timestamp
                 );
```

This implements:  "Get me all rows from `my_tbl` where no row with the same id exists that has a larger timestamp".  That is a fancy way of saying "get me the row with the maximum timestamp for each row.

For performance, this should have an index on `mytble(id, timestamp)`.

Note the removal of the single quotes on `timestamp`.